# Custom sorting a list knowing the order of a few items

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list using a custom order with only knowing the order of a few items. The rest of the items should be considered "Other" in essence where the order doesn't matter.

For instance, I have the following list where I made an attempt to sort just a few of the items. The code below will fail with a KeyError because it can't find Badminton or Cricket.

```
myList = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Badminton', 'Cricket']

myOrder = {"Baseball" : 1, "Basketball" : 2, "Football" : 3}

myList.sort(key=lambda val: myOrder[val])
```

How do I take into account of the rest of the items in the list without caring about their order?

Comment: myList.sort(key=lambda val: myOrder.get(val, 0))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, you can use `myOrder.get` as the sort-key, because `None` (the default-value `get` returns) is always lesser than any integer:

```
>>> myList = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Badminton', 'Cricket']
>>> myOrder = {"Baseball" : 1, "Basketball" : 2, "Football" : 3}
>>> myList.sort(key=myOrder.get)
>>> myList
['Badminton', 'Cricket', 'Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Football']
```

In Python 3, you cannot order `NoneType` and `int`, so you will have to wrap the call to `get` in another function like user234461's solution from the comments:

```
myList.sort(key=lambda val: myOrder.get(val, 0))
```

> Thank you! Is it possible to have them placed towards the end of the newly sorted list?

Certainly, you could use `float('inf')` as the default-value for the call to `get`:

```
>>> myList = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Badminton', 'Cricket']
>>> myList.sort(key=lambda x: myOrder.get(x, float('inf')))
>>> myList
['Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Football', 'Badminton', 'Cricket']
```

edit 2: Or you could bake the default ordering into your `myOrder` dictionary by using a `defaultdict`. I like that.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> myList = ['Football', 'Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Badminton', 'Cricket']
>>> myOrder = defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))
>>> myOrder.update({"Baseball" : 1, "Basketball" : 2, "Football" : 3})
>>> myList.sort(key=myOrder.__getitem__)
>>> myList
['Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Football', 'Badminton', 'Cricket']
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to have them placed towards the end of the newly sorted list?